# What are the gamemaker alarm limitations?

Tags: alarm, gml

I'm a little confused about this one. Is it a limit of eleven alarms in my game? or in an object? or an instance of an object?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every *Instance* of an Object in GML has 12 alarms that can be used (starting from 0 and ending at 11).

PGmath's Sggestion:

> If you really need more alarms you can make your own by having a variable which you manually decrement by 1 each step, then test if equal to 0 to perform an action.

This information is from the GML Wiki on [Alarms](http://gamemaker.wikidot.com/alarm). You may also find the associated [FAQ for Alarms](http://gamemaker.wikidot.com/alarm-faq) helpful.

Comment: @david If you really need more alarms you can make your own by having a variable which you manually decrement by 1 each step, then test if equal to 0 to perform an action.